# Calling locationManager within a IBAction function

Tags: swift, xcode, locationmanager

I'm working on a weather application and I want the user to get data about the weather either by inserting a location or by the current GPS location.

For the GPS location, there is a push button in the interface that can be pressed. At the click of the button, I want to call the locationManager function, but it does not work. Do you think it's something linked with the scope?

I simply put the locationManager function into the **IBAction** function of the button. That's because I do not know how to call locationManager within IBAction.

[image]

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    let key = "d79ac3fea08fac5d21deeabef00*****"
    var lat = 11.344533
    var lon = 104.33322
    let managLoc = CLLocationManager()

    @IBAction func locationOption(_ sender: Any, forEvent event: UIEvent) {
        func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
            let location = locations[0]
            lat = location.coordinate.latitude
            lon = location.coordinate.longitude
            Alamofire.request("https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=\(lat)&lon=\(lon)&appid=\(key)").responseJSON {
                response in
                if let responseStr = response.result.value {
                    let jsonResponse = JSON(responseStr)
                    let jsonWeather = jsonResponse["weather"].array![0]
                    let jsonTemp = jsonResponse["main"]
                    let iconName = jsonWeather["icon"].stringValue

                    self.locationLabel.text = jsonResponse["name"].stringValue
                    self.typeView.image = UIImage(named: iconName)
                    self.typeLabel.text = jsonWeather["main"].stringValue
                    self.tempLabel.text = "\(Int(round(jsonTemp["temp"].doubleValue-273.15)))"

                    let date = Date()
                    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
                    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEEE"
                    self.dayLabel.text = dateFormatter.string(from: date)

                    }
            }
            self.managLoc.stopUpdatingLocation()
        }

        func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Get the locationManager functions out of the action

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    let key = "d79ac3fea08fac5d21deeabef00*****"
    var lat = 11.344533
    var lon = 104.33322
    let managLoc = CLLocationManager()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       managLoc.delegate = self
    }
    @IBAction func locationOption(_ sender: Any, forEvent event: UIEvent) {
       self.managLoc.startUpdatingLocation()
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        let location = locations[0]
        lat = location.coordinate.latitude
        lon = location.coordinate.longitude
        Alamofire.request("https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=\(lat)&lon=\(lon)&appid=\(key)").responseJSON {
            response in
            if let responseStr = response.result.value {
                let jsonResponse = JSON(responseStr)
                let jsonWeather = jsonResponse["weather"].array![0]
                let jsonTemp = jsonResponse["main"]
                let iconName = jsonWeather["icon"].stringValue

                self.locationLabel.text = jsonResponse["name"].stringValue
                self.typeView.image = UIImage(named: iconName)
                self.typeLabel.text = jsonWeather["main"].stringValue
                self.tempLabel.text = "\(Int(round(jsonTemp["temp"].doubleValue-273.15)))"

                let date = Date()
                let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
                dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEEE"
                self.dayLabel.text = dateFormatter.string(from: date)

                }
        }
        self.managLoc.stopUpdatingLocation()
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }

}
```

Comment: Trying that it says "The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCLErrorDomain error 0.)"

Comment: Do you run in simulator / device ?

Comment: I solved it by editing scheme (Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme... and choosing a default location). Thank you a lot, man!